# Add class to existing HTML via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-73 gallery-columns-0 gallery-size-thumbnail'>
<div class='gallery-item'>
    <span class='gallery-icon landscape'>
        <img width="300" height="200" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="Aurore, Watercolour" aria-describedby="gallery-1-205" />
    </span>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a class alongside `gallery-item`.

How do I do this with jQuery?

Comment: on which element you want to add it?

Comment: `gallery-item` so it reads `gallery-item col-md-4` :)

Comment: What class do you want to add? Where did you get stuck, you have over two thousand rep (as I write this), you know we expect more than a "*I want (you) to do this for me*" posted in lieu of a question.

Comment: i think you should search first, you will easily find answers for these small questions

Comment: @MandeepSingh Good advice, Mandeep - I'll definitely do this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery [**addclass**](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method

Select the `<div class='gallery-item'>` with class selector

```
$(".gallery-item").addClass("col-md-4")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('gallery-item').addClass('col-md-4')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".gallery-item").addClass("col-md-4");
```

To add a class to the `.gallery-item` element. This basically just selects the existing class, `gallery-item` and adds `col-md-4`.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".gallery-item").addClass("new-class")`